# How to include advertisements (ads) on google cast (pre-rolls, mid-rolls)

Tags: google-cast

I'm trying to implement Custom Receiver and play pre- mid- rolls of advertisement while casting videos. According to schema on this https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#choose-a-receiver page it is possible to include pre-, mid-, post- advertising. I don't know how to exactly do that (the way to do that is to use custom player that can play ads by client-ads-id). 
Can anybody help in that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is available. But according to [Google Cast SDK Additional Developer Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/terms#1introduction):

> **Advertising**
>
> 6.1 Google may in the future make advertising available via its APIs. Such advertising will appear in connection with your content or service only if you opt in. If Google makes such advertising available, and you choose to serve such advertising, Google may share revenue from that advertising with you pursuant to the advertising terms and conditions made available at the time you opt in to such advertising.